How to track specific features in a gradient tape in Tensorflow without causing memory error?
I am manually trying to compute the gradient of how each one of the output features changes with each of the trainable parameters of my model. The model consists of several CNN layers and a last dense layer for outputting the sequences of size (sequence_length, output_features). I need to track each of the individual output_features with a gradient tape. For that, I already tried just taking the output of the hz vector and then calculating the gradient of hz[output_feature]. However, when hz[output_feature] is created, it doesn't have any influence on the trainable parameters and thus the gradient of the output_features w.r.t. the trainable parameters return zero.
I have come up with the following solution:
`def train_step(data, labels, current_epoch, use_xAI=False):
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
hz = self.generator_model.get_layer('generator')([ez, c] if self.cond_dim > 0 else ez)                        # synthetic latent vector tensor shape: (units, sequence_length, output_features)
hz_unstack = tf.unstack(hz, axis=2)                                                                        # Unstack the synthetic latent vector to get individual output_feature tensors

for output_feature in range(hz.shape[-1]):
    dX_dW_layer.append(tape.gradient(hz_unstack[output_feature], layer.kernel))
    dX_dB_layer.append(tape.gradient(hz_unstack[output_feature], layer.bias))`

Thus I am creating output_features number of lists, and then taking the gradients of each of those lists w.r.t. the trainable parameters, which works. However, this takes a lot of gradient_tape memory, since it has to watch output_features number of lists (which could be as high as 144.) This causes the memory of even a CPU with 160GB of memory to crash. Does anyone have a clue how to track the gradient of each individual output_feature w.r.t. the trainable parameters of my model without using output_features number of gradient tapes? I am aware that this could be easily done in PyTorch, but at this point, it is not viable for me to transfer my code to pytorch.

You can use tape.jacobian.

Unfortunately, I have tried using the tape.jacobian, but that computes a matrix of size (Batchsize, suquence_length, weights_i, weights_j, output_features) Which is about a (96, 40, 96, 96, 96) matrix. I would then average this over the first two dimensions, which thus creates a lot of (unnecessary) additional computational effort and increases the computation time beyond control.

You could first average over the "superfluous" dimensions (batch size and sequence length, it seems) in the tensors, then take the jacobian afterwards.
